# Find phrases with 2 words while negating if certain words appear in between

Tags: java, regex

Here is my regex challenge regexp query.
Looking for phrases that has "love" and "much" but DOES NOT include "apple" OR "pear" in between. 
example :

```
I love pear very much  <-- NO MATCH ("pear" is between "love" and "much")
I love apple banana and pear very much  <-- NO MATCH 
I love banana very much  <--  MATCH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with a negative lookahead:

```
^.*love(?:(?!apple|pear).)*much.*$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hbiwwD/2)

Comment: Hi Thibaut. Thank you. Seems like thie regexp fails on this one : "I love banana pear very" without the MUCH word it still shows a match

Comment: Dear Thibaut. I might need to convert this to POSIX regexp which does not support "?:"... This is for mysql query. I tried hours to do that but with no success... Do you have an idea regarding this ?

Comment: @Irad, It's an other question, but with mysql, you can achieve it with multiple where clause like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c9011/6)

Comment: Sorry. I will know to open new questions. This is wonderful my friend. truly appreciate it ! I was so hooked with the REGEXP that I didn't think at that direction :)